# What are reasonable scenarios to use GenerationTime.INSERT in the Hibernate @Generated annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wonder about the behavior of Hibernate regarding fields annotated with **@Generated(value=GenerationTime.INSERT)** when I do an update on the entity.

I have an entity with the following fields (which are populated by database triggers, the first one on insert, the second one on insert and for each update):

```
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name="created_by", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String createdBy;

@Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
@Column(name="updated_by", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String updatedBy;
```

- When I load an entity from the database, both fields are populated - as expected
- When I receive the entity back from the web-ui, both fields will be null - as expected since they weren't bound to any form field.

After calling

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
```

the createdBy field will be null but the updatedBy field will be set to the correct value (created by the database).

So the entity no longer contains the values from the database - an undesired behavior.

For my situation can solve the issue
- I could change the GenerationTime to ALWAYS - but this seems to be confusing since createdBy is really only set  when the entity is inserted.
- I could do a refresh on the entity - but I would like to avoid the extra call.

1. What is the best practice for the described situation? **Are there better options that avoid an explicit call of refresh and don't obscure the semantic of fields modified only on insert?**
2. **What are reasonable scenarios to use @Generated(value=GenerationTime.INSERT)?**

Answer (score -1):

can you try like this.
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
    @Column(name="create_date", insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Calendar createDate;

Comment: This doesn't answer the general question which is about the semantic of GenerationTime.INSERT.